# How to display JSON data in angularjs success function?

Tags: angularjs, json

[image]Hi I am developing Angularjs application and getting some data from Web API. I am able to receive data. I can confirm this because i can see in fiddler and browser developer tool as well. Below is my code. I am returning data as json from web api. I am returning below object.

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj);
```

Object obj contains some fields(data);

In browser i can see response as below.

```
{"ID":11,"project_id":1,"levels":1,"icon":1,"description":1,"summary":1,"output":1,"owner":1,"role":1,"objectives":1,"reporting":1,"performance_indicators":1,"success":0,"Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Updated":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}
```

This is my angular code.

```
var saveSubs = ProjectSetting_Service.AddProcessSettings(sub);
            saveSubs.then(function (data) {
                alert((data.data));
                alert((data.obj));
            }, function (error) {
            })
```

This is my service.js code

```
this.AddProcessSettings = function (sub) {

        $http.post('/api/NCT_ProcessSettings/', sub).success(function (response) { alert(response); });
    }
```

In alert i want to see response data. May i get some help? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You misspelled `alert`. Should be `console.log`.

Comment: Have you tried just alerting `data`? It looks to me like `data` doesn't contain a property `data`

Comment: what do you see inside data?

Comment: I can see just [object object] in alert...But in response i can see. I will update the screenshot above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According your response, it does not have data in it,

just put the alert as,

```
var saveSubs = ProjectSetting_Service.AddProcessSettings(sub);
            saveSubs.then(function (data) {
                alert((data));
                alert((data.project_id));
            }, function (error) {
            })
```

**UPDATE**

Your services is not returning anything, just change the service response to return it,

then you can access the data like `alert(data.data);`

Comment: for that you need to use the property that you want to see, use data.project_id and see

Comment: I have posted service.js above. Does it has any problem in returning data?

Comment: yes. i will share. My id 345 595 037 password f72w5x

Comment: send the password

Comment: password is f72w5x